# Find the equation of a line through origin

Tags: limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}→\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{$(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{$(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$
Find a line through the origin of the form $y = mx$, such that the limit of $f$ as
$(x, y)$ approaches the origin along this line is equal to $\frac{3}{10}.$
$$$$
I started the solution replacing the equation $y=mx$ in the function $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\ f(x,y)=\frac{3}{10}$, so I got $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ x^2m}{x^2+m^2x^2}=$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ m}{1+m^2}=\frac{3}{10} =>$ $3m^2-10m+3=0$, and here I solved for m where I found m=3 and m=$\frac{1}{3}$, therefore $y=3x$ and $y=\frac{1}{3}x.\\ \text{Can somebody tell me if thats correct or not? If not could you show me the right way please?}$

Comment: Your work is good, and you have correctly found two such lines.